# Converting a normal function to generic function for optimization

Tags: java, generics, optimization, logging

I had implemented a logging function as following:

```
void log (String output)
{
  if(debug)
  {
    String val = <some string captured>;
    Log.write("Logging: " + val + output, this.handle);
  }
}
```

This `log` is used at several places as,

```
log("value is " + str + " " + val);  // 'str','val' can be a string or class with '.toString()'
log("error: " + e1 + ". Exiting."); // 'e1' can be a class with overloaded '.tostring()'
```

Now, the problem is (got as code review comments), the `class` object to string conversion will happen even if `debug` condition is not ON. At several places, this will lead to unwanted performance downgrade.

I don't want to clutter my code by putting that `if()` condition everywhere where only `output` matters and rest of the things are repeated. What is the best way of solving this problem using Java facilities?

I thought of using generics:

```
<T> void log (String output, T arg)
{
  if(debug)
  {
    String val = <some string captured>;
    Log.write("Logging: " + val + output + arg.toString(), this.handle);
  }
}
```

Will this approach make a good optimization ? Also, can I elegantly extend this generic function to take multiple arguments ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need generics - you can use `Object`:

```
void log (String output, Object arg) { ... }
```

For multiple objects you can use varargs and `MessageFormat`, for example, as follows:

```
void log (String pattern, Object... args) {
    if (debug) {
        Log.write(MessageFormat.format(pattern, args));
    }
}
```

.

```
log("value is {0} {1}", str, val);
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. One more query: without the `debug` condition, still the `log` function will be called. I fear that, I can get code review comment for that as well. Can I tell them that, even saving a function call would be a premature optimization ? (note: function is called several times while execution)

Comment: @iammilind: I don't know. The typical approach is to place debug condition around function call, though calling function that does nothing shouldn't seriously hamper performance.

Comment: I see. It's better to retain the typical approach, where the logs are enclosed in `if()` condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't understand the reason to use generics in your case. Just use varargs (look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and string formatting (String.format).

Or use existing logging libraries like log5j: http://code.google.com/p/log5j/